# C++: How to separate lines of a txt file

Tags: c++, parsing, io

I'm trying to write a code that pulls from a txt file (input.txt) that looks like this:

```
1,2,3
Hello
2,3,4
Music
1,3,4
Dodie
3,0,1
Kitty
5,1,0
Cheese
```

And prints out the word as many times as the numbers above it added up. So the first one would be 1+2+3=6, so it would print:
            Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello

```
Current Output:
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
2,3,4
2,3,4
2,3,4
2,3,4
2,3,4
Music
Music
Music
Music
Music
1,3,4
1,3,4
1,3,4
1,3,4
1,3,4
Dodie
Dodie
Dodie
Dodie
Dodie
3,0,1
3,0,1
3,0,1
3,0,1
3,0,1
Kitty
Kitty
Kitty
Kitty
Kitty
5,1,0
5,1,0
5,1,0
5,1,0
5,1,0
Cheese
Cheese
Cheese
Cheese
Cheese
```

I can't figure out how to pull a specific line separately/separate the lines of the txt file.

Current code (we aren't supposed to use namespace std, but I was trying to figure out the basics first. It is also supposed to print into another txt file called output.txt):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX=7;
int main() {

        ifstream inFile ("input.txt");
        char input[MAX];

        while (inFile) {
                int num = 5;
                inFile.getline(input, MAX);

                for(int n = 0; n < num; n++) {

                        printf(input);
                        printf("\n");

                } // end for
        } // end while

        inFile.close();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does your assignment requirements allow the use of  `std::string` and `std::stirngstream`? [They can make this brutally easy.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7868998/4581301)

Comment: @user4581301, yes, I'm pretty sure we can.

Comment: Are you not “supposed to use namespace std” as in “the standard library”, which seems overbroad, or as in `using namespace std;`, which is widely derided?